# BigCommerce Stencil how can I nest the {{filter}} Handlebars Helper?

Tags: filter, handlebars.js, bigcommerce

I'm a complete amateur when it comes to javascript and templating language, but I know just enough to get by for our small business. We are using a customized bigcommerce stencil theme (cornerstone). I understand conceptually why handlebars helpers work, but I don't understand the details behind HOW they work. I've tried reading the documentation, but I don't understand all the terminology so I'm still lost.

I want to display the lowest price for products that have bulk discounts as well as per unit price if it's a case-packed product. The problem is, bigcommerce doesn't let you call the product bulk pricing within the Category page, so we are trying to use custom fields instead. I thought maybe I could achieve the intended result by "nesting" the {{filter}} helper, but it doesn't work. Here is the code section in the category template:

```
{{#if price}}
    {{#filter custom_fields 'As low as' property='name'}}
        <div>As low as {{value}}{{#filter custom_fields 'Price Unit' property='name'}} / {{value}}{{/filter}}</div>
        <div>with bulk discounts</div>
    {{else}}
        <div class="listItem-price">{{> components/products/price price=price}}</div>
    {{/filter}}
{{/if}}
```

How would you approach this?

Answer (score 2):

What exactly are you trying to accomplish with the filter function - as I understand it, it looks like you're trying to access two neighboring custom fields within a single loop?

If that's the case, I would try using a nested `{{#each}}` loop - you'll notice that when you nest loops like this, sometimes you'll need to try to reach above the nested context by using `../` -- honestly, it's not very consistent, and sometimes you'll need two rounds (as we did here), sometimes you'll need one - that's something I basically use trial and error to determine in different points

```
{{#each custom_fields}}
  {{#if name '==' 'First Custom Field Name'}}
    First Value: {{value}}
    {{#each ../../custom_fields}}
      {{#if name '==' 'Second Custom Field Name'}}
        Second Value: {{value}}
      {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

If you'd like a less hacky way to do this, I would suggest using the `stencil-utils` library's handy "Fetch Product By ID" function:

(https://github.com/bigcommerce/stencil-utils)

What you can do is call `utils.api.product.getById(productID, {template}, callback)` -- what this does is basically fetch an HTML response from BigCommerce with a Product Template - handy for getting data that's specific to product-pages only, but outside of those pages - usually you would use `product-view.html` as a base -- if you check `quickview.js`, this is how BigCommerce populates the "Quick View" modal on product cards.

This is handy for fetching all the data that would be rendered out on a product page anywhere else that you need it - category pages, content pages, blog posts, etc.

Anyways, a few steps to accomplish this:

First, expose the `id` of your Products on the Category Cards. You would just go to `card.html` and add a `data-id="{{id}}"` attribute, so that you can cycle through each one on page load.

Example: `<div class="card" data-id="{{id}}"> ... </div>`

Next, we'll build out a custom template that just contains pertinent information for the bulk discounts. Basically, you can just use `product-view`, but to avoid giant payloads, we can create a new template:

`templates/components/products/bulk-discount-rate-fetcher.html`:

```
<div data-bulk-rates="{{json product.bulk_discount_rates}}"></div>
```

Yep, that's it!

Now the meat of the function, we will iterate through all product cards on the category page, and we'll use stencil-utils to populate our custom template with a simple JSON data tag of the bulk discounts:

```
import utils from '@bigcommerce/stencil-utils';

$('.card').each((index, el) => {
  const id = $(el).data('id');
  utils.api.product.getById(id, { template: 'products/bulk-discount-rate-fetcher' }, (err, response) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    const bulkRates = $(response).data('bulk-rates');
    console.log(bulkRates);
  });
})
```

Result:

[image]

If you’re looking to incorporate the product price into this customization as well, that would require some additional work.